# How to read Dom values in Elm?

Tags: elm

So I am struggling to get this simple thing done
I need to read the width of a dom element as soon as my app starts and set it as the width of another element. 
Basically its like this I have some Tabs which are nothing but a bunch of div elements. A selected tab will have an underline for which I am using a span to get the underline done. My question is how can I read the width of a particular dom element as soon as the dom loads and then set the width of the another element

Comment: I think this video describes a similar problem with a possible solution: https://youtu.be/LZj_1qVURL0?t=694

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper approach to that would be to use [Flags](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html). In that case, you use JavaScript to read the DOM, parse the information and then send it to the Elm app via `Flags`:

```
var app = Elm.Main.init({
  node: document.getElementById('elm'),
  flags: document.getElementById('my-other-element').offfsetWidth,
});
```